# Convert start time and total duration to elapsed time per hour

Tags: r, time, duration

I have data on start time ('startTime', a date-time variable, `POSIXct`) and duration in minutes ('duration_minutes'):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                 startTime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:15:31",
                                          "2018-01-02 23:43:00",
                                          "2018-01-03 11:00:11")), 
                 duration_minutes = c(315, 120, 45))
```

I want to convert the start time and duration to elapsed time per hour, for each hour, from the hour of the start time to the last hour at the end of the duration:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                        startTime = c("2018-01-01 12:15:31","2018-01-01 13:00:00",
                                "2018-01-01 14:00:00","2018-01-01 15:00:00",
                                "2018-01-01 16:00:00","2018-01-01 17:00:00",

                                "2018-01-02 23:43:00","2018-01-03 00:00:00",
                                "2018-01-03 01:00:00",

                                "2018-01-03 11:00:11"),
                        duration_minutes = c(44.48, 60, 60, 60, 60, 30.5, 17, 60, 43, 45))
```

Please, advice with the possible solution.

Comment: We would be interested in what you've tried so far.

Comment: Glad, you here @jay.sf. Tried to iterate through for loop, well - failed with everything i tried. If you have any idea - i'll be glad to understand the solution.

Comment: It would be smartest of all you'd add your attempts to your question above so that we can help you best.

Comment: Can you please clarify the logic for duration. See e.g. id 2: add 120 minutes to 23:43:00 and you end up at 01:43:00 (next day) and the duration for that last hour (01) is 43 minutes, as you show in desired results. Then apply the same logic on id 1: add 315 minutes to 12:15:31, you end up at 17:30:31. Then duration for the last hour (17) should be 30.51, not 15 as you write. Cheers

Comment: @henrik you are totally correct, thanks for clarification on this. Let me explain, the desired result dataset was built manually by hand, in order to demonstrate the pattern as output. The logic is next, we have total duration (ex: 120 min) for each activity, and startTime of that activity, well we need to spread this duration among the hours it took, let's say startTime = 12:00:00, duration = 120, then it took 2 hours and 2 whole intervals of 60 min each, 12:00:00-13:00:00 = 60 min, then 13:00:00-14:00:00 = 60 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

df <-
  setDT(df)[, start_ceiling := ceiling_date(startTime, "hour", change_on_boundary = TRUE)] %>%
  .[, `:=` (
    reps = ifelse(
      startTime + (duration_minutes * 60) <= start_ceiling, 1, pmax(2, floor(duration_minutes / 60) + 1)
    ),
    initial_diff = as.numeric(difftime(start_ceiling[1], startTime[1], units = "mins"))
  ), by = id] %>%
  .[, df[df[, rep(.I, reps)]]] %>%
  .[, startTime := pmax(startTime, floor_date(startTime, "hour") + hours(0:(.N - 1))), by = id] %>%
  .[reps > 1, duration_minutes := c(initial_diff[.N], 
                                    rep(60, reps[.N] - 2),
                                    (duration_minutes[.N] - initial_diff[.N]) %% 60), by = id] %>%
  .[!(duration_minutes == 0 & reps > 1), ] %>%
  .[, c("reps", "start_ceiling", "initial_diff") := NULL]
```

I've tested this with all the scenarios we've gathered so far, and this is the output:

```
    id           startTime duration_minutes
 1:  1 2018-01-01 12:15:31         44.48333
 2:  1 2018-01-01 13:00:00         60.00000
 3:  1 2018-01-01 14:00:00         60.00000
 4:  1 2018-01-01 15:00:00         60.00000
 5:  1 2018-01-01 16:00:00         60.00000
 6:  1 2018-01-01 17:00:00         30.51667
 7:  2 2018-01-02 23:43:00         17.00000
 8:  2 2018-01-03 00:00:00         60.00000
 9:  2 2018-01-03 01:00:00         43.00000
10:  3 2018-01-03 11:00:11         45.00000
11:  4 2018-01-04 10:00:00         60.00000
12:  4 2018-01-04 11:00:00          5.00000
13:  5 2018-01-05 00:00:00         60.00000
14:  6 2018-01-06 11:35:00         25.00000
15:  6 2018-01-06 12:00:00         10.00000
16:  7 2018-01-07 00:00:00         60.00000
17:  7 2018-01-07 01:00:00         60.00000
```

Data used:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  startTime = as.POSIXct(
    c(
      "2018-01-01 12:15:31",
      "2018-01-02 23:43:00",
      "2018-01-03 11:00:11",
      "2018-01-04 10:00:00",
      "2018-01-05 00:00:00",
      "2018-01-06 11:35:00",
      "2018-01-07 00:00:00"
    )
  ),
  duration_minutes = c(315, 120, 45, 65, 60, 35, 120)
)

df

  id           startTime duration_minutes
1  1 2018-01-01 12:15:31              315
2  2 2018-01-02 23:43:00              120
3  3 2018-01-03 11:00:11               45
4  4 2018-01-04 10:00:00               65
5  5 2018-01-05 00:00:00               60
6  6 2018-01-06 11:35:00               35
7  7 2018-01-07 00:00:00              120
```

Comment: This doesn't seem work for e.g. start "2018-01-03 11:35:00" and duration 35.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @Henrik - `pmax` should solve the issue

Comment: Absolutely brilliant as the solution! Thanks a lot, I should take some additional materials on data.table, this is great tool.

Comment: You're welcome! `data.table` is a nice library indeed - and very fast as well, good decision to delve more into it, inevitable with large data frames.

Comment: Found the next issue: when we have startTime that starts exactly in 00:00 (like: 10:00:00) then in result we have first row of segment (by id) as 1, else 60 up to the end and last row of the segment would be incorrectly calculated. check this example dataset with this occurrence.

Comment: df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 startTime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:15:31",
                                          "2018-01-02 23:43:00",
                                          "2018-01-03 11:00:11",
                                          "2018-01-04 10:00:00")),
                 duration_minutes = c(315, 120, 45, 65))

Comment: Thanks for flagging @Oleksandr - here the reason was that `difftime` converted 60 into 1. I've fixed this by explicitly asking for the output in `mins`, and have placed this at the beginning of the code to avoid repetitions. Please check and let me know, however I think this should cover all scenarios.

Comment: @arg0naut, almost perfect! Now it covers the initial task 99,99%, well there is a little issue with whole intervals, just for example, there is no need to fix this now: when we have 00:00:00 as start time and round duration like 120 min, the expected result should be 2 intervals by 60 mins, it gives 3 intervals 60+60+0, well it's even more like feature for me, since the durations of the original dataset mostly has numbers as doubles, so that little piece would be placed in t hat 3rd interval. Tested on fresh data, it works great. I wish you all the best!

Comment: You're completely right this is a side effect - I've edited my solution with a line that filters these out (this would also keep the cases - if they would occur for whatever reason - where 0 was present from the beginning. You can comment out this line as well, wouldn't affect anything). And you're welcome, it was a nice challenge!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(df)
df[ , ceil_start := ceiling_date(start, "hour", change_on_boundary = TRUE)]

df[ , {
  if(difftime(ceil_start, start, units = "min") > dur) {
    .SD[ , .(start, dur)]
  } else {
    end <- start + dur * 60
    time <- c(start,
              seq(from = ceil_start,
                  to = floor_date(end, "hour"),
                  by = "hour"),
              end)
    .(start = head(time, -1), dur = `units<-`(diff(time), "mins"))
  }
},
by = id]

#     id               start           dur
# 1:   1 2018-01-01 12:15:31 44.48333 mins
# 2:   1 2018-01-01 13:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 3:   1 2018-01-01 14:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 4:   1 2018-01-01 15:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 5:   1 2018-01-01 16:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 6:   1 2018-01-01 17:00:00 30.51667 mins
# 7:   2 2018-01-02 23:43:00 17.00000 mins
# 8:   2 2018-01-03 00:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 9:   2 2018-01-03 01:00:00 43.00000 mins
# 10:  3 2018-01-03 11:00:11 45.00000 mins
# 11:  4 2018-01-03 11:35:00 25.00000 mins
# 12:  4 2018-01-03 12:00:00 10.00000 mins
# 13:  5 2018-01-03 00:00:00 60.00000 mins
# 14:  5 2018-01-03 01:00:00  0.00000 mins
```

---

#### Explanation

Convert `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT`). Round up start times to nearest hour (`ceiling_date(start, "hour", ...)`. Use `change_on_boundary = TRUE` for easier handling of times without minutes and seconds (not in the data, but tested).

To handle cases when the end time (start + duration) is in the same hour as the start time (e.g. id = 3), check if difference between rounded time and start time is larger than duration (`if(difftime(ceil_start, start, units = "min") > dur))`). If so, just select the start and duration columns (`.SD[ , .(start, dur)`).

For other cases (`else`), calculate end time: `end <- start + dur * 60`. Create a sequence from the up-rounded start time ('ceil_start'), to the down-rounded end time, with an hourly increment (`seq(from = ceil_start, to = floor_date(end, "hour"), by = "hour")`). Concatenate with 'start' and 'end' times. Return all times except the last (`head(time, -1)` and calculate difference between time steps in minutes (`` `units<-`(diff(time), "mins") ``).

For times with H:M:S = 00:00:00 and duration is a multiple of 60 min, like id = 5, the current solution gives a row with a duration of 0 minutes for the last hour. While waiting for a more elegant solution, a quick and dirty way is just to delete such rows with duration = 0.

---

#### Data

Please note that I have added a case not included in original data, id = 4 (see also [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650870/convert-start-time-and-total-duration-to-elapsed-time-per-hour/54660125?noredirect=1#comment96112139_54660125)) and id = 5.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                 start = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:15:31",
                                      "2018-01-02 23:43:00",
                                      "2018-01-03 11:00:11",
                                      "2018-01-03 11:35:00",
                                      "2018-01-03 00:00:00")), 
                 dur = c(315, 120, 45, 35, 60))
```

Comment: thanks! I should say that this is very elegant solution, well the issue is the same, when it goes to case like this, start = "2018-01-03 00:00:00", dur = 60, the result should be the 1 interval with 60 mins, but it gives 1 interval with 3600 mins.

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks for your feedback. I have now set `units` of all groups to minutes. Please also include the additional cases mentioned in comments and any necessary information in your _question_. Much easier for people trying to help. Next time please provide data of sufficient complexity ;) Cheers

Comment: could you please advice with this error: Warning messages:
1: In if (difftime(ceil_start, start, units = "min") > dur) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used on this dataset : df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
                 start = ymd_hms(c("2018-01-01 10:00:00",
                                   "2018-01-01 10:00:00",
                                   "2018-01-01 10:00:00",
                                   "2018-01-01 00:00:00")), 
                 dur = c(59,61,40,172))

Comment: So there can be several rows per 'id'? My solution does account for that. I have to reiterate: please provide data of _sufficient complexity_ in the actual question. Otherwise people spend time on solutions which doesn't solve your problem. Cheers

Comment: Fair enough, @henrik, so now i was able to include the unique id ($index) for each row to the data and set by = index, it goes well from with it and completes what i need. Another little benefit that I could track what rows exactly were elapsed. So, now I got desired result, thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked! (as you probably noted, a "not" was missing above - I meant "My solution does _not_ account for that") ;) Just doing it rowwise is the way to go, yes.